Finding branches of log and arg, without the positive imaginary axis
I want to find a log branch cut $ g:\mathbb C\setminus A \to\mathbb C $, and an arg branch cut $ f:\mathbb C\setminus A\to\mathbb C $, where A = { $ ti: t \ge 0 $ }.
I'm having trouble understanding what to think. So for example, for arg, I want to "rotate" the axis such that the negative reals are now the positive imaginary - so $ Arg(-iz) $ satisfies this condition.
However, for example, $Arg(iz)$ is discontinuous at the positive imaginary as well - I can take $ z = i + a $, and $ z = i - a$, $a > 0 $, and when $ a$ approaches $0$,  at $z_0 = i $ it's not continuous.
I lack understanding of how to work with branches. Could someone please help me?

Do you want to find a branch cut, or, after having one, a branch of those functions on the domain left by the cut? Because it seems like you have the branch cut defined ...

I apologize, I didn't understand what you meant. I want to find a branch cut of arg on $\mathbb C$, without the positive imaginary axis. for example, for the function f, I thought Arg(iz) or Arg(-iz) can be considered what I need. I might have mixed things up...

I'm just pointing out a terminology issue. You want to find a branch. You already have a branch cut, that is just the line that connects $0$ to $\infty$. --- That being said, if $z=ti, t>0$, then $-iz = t >0$ so you don't want that one. $Arg(iz)$ instead works.
